# What does `<=` do with python sets and booleans?

Tags: python, shutil

I found some code in the `shutil` module in the standard library that I do not understand.

`_use_fd_functions` ends up holding a truthy/falsy value, and it's initialized like this:

```
_use_fd_functions = ({os.open, os.stat, os.unlink, os.rmdir} <=
                     os.supports_dir_fd and
                     os.listdir in os.supports_fd and
                     os.stat in os.supports_follow_symlinks)
```

`{os.open, os.stat, os.unlink, os.rmdir}` are all functions, and the right argument to `<=` looks like a boolean, but according to the source, they're functions and sets of functions.

I was not able to recreate this behavior in the Python 3.5.2 repl: (tracebacks removed)

```
>>> {lambda x: x} <= True
TypeError: unorderable types: set() <= bool()
>>> {True} <= True
TypeError: unorderable types: set() <= bool()
>>> {lambda x: x} <= (lambda x: x+1)
TypeError: unorderable types: set() <= function()
>>> {lambda x: x} <= (lambda x: x+1) in {lambda x: x+1}
TypeError: unorderable types: set() <= function()
```

Of course, since an experienced developer was not able to decipher the code in a few seconds, the code is being too smart. But how does it work, and what does it do?

Comment: Is the source code in Python 2? There, comparing a `set` to a `boolean` does not throw a `TypeError`. I don't remember the rule (which is part of the reason such a behavior was removed), but something clever is going on here.

Comment: I don't really understand what this does but `{lambda x: x} <= (lambda x: x+1) in {lambda x: x+1}` returns `False` in Python 2.7 btw.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The path to the `shutil` I read is `C:\Python35\Lib\shutil.py`. I expect it to be Python 3.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer is found in the [os module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f15fa87e5a66c0000f63be5065ddee4a52d5660f/Lib/os.py#L104-L121):

```
_set = set()
_add("HAVE_FACCESSAT",  "access")
_add("HAVE_FCHMODAT",   "chmod")
_add("HAVE_FCHOWNAT",   "chown")
_add("HAVE_FSTATAT",    "stat")
_add("HAVE_FUTIMESAT",  "utime")
_add("HAVE_LINKAT",     "link")
_add("HAVE_MKDIRAT",    "mkdir")
_add("HAVE_MKFIFOAT",   "mkfifo")
_add("HAVE_MKNODAT",    "mknod")
_add("HAVE_OPENAT",     "open")
_add("HAVE_READLINKAT", "readlink")
_add("HAVE_RENAMEAT",   "rename")
_add("HAVE_SYMLINKAT",  "symlink")
_add("HAVE_UNLINKAT",   "unlink")
_add("HAVE_UNLINKAT",   "rmdir")
_add("HAVE_UTIMENSAT",  "utime")
supports_dir_fd = _set
```

`os.supports_dir_fd` is a set of functions.

In Python `and` have [lower precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `<=` so your set comparison is evaluated first. For `set` this operator checks if the first set [is a subset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) of the second set.

`os.supports_dir_fd` lists the kind of file operations you can do. This can differ between operating systems, so the `os` module takes different code paths depending on the current environment. For each function, `_add` will check if it is allowed on the current OS. So the intent of the code snippet you are asking about is to see if the operations `open`, `stat`, `unlink` and `rmdir` are supported, and then it does some more checks for specific behaviours that `shutil` wants to use. In the end, `_use_fd_functions` will tell if `shutil` should use file descriptor functions ("fd") at all, depending on what you can do in the current environment.

Comment: Maybe I'm being slow but I'm struggling to piece together the intent of the original code from this. Are you able to state it on a high level?

Comment: Appreciated, it makes a lot more sense to me now